# How did Agent C realize who the traitor was?

Tags: plot-explanation, men-in-black-international

In *Men in Black: International*, after Chris Hemsworth retrieves the weapon, he talks with Agent C at the after-party.

> Agent C: I don't know how you do it, but you just keep on doing it.
>
> Agent H: Yeah, whats that C?
>
> Agent C: Saving the world from total destruction twice, in as many
>   years. I mean, what are the odds?
>
> Agent H: What are the odds?

They kind of look at each other and start thinking.

Then we see Agent C in High T's office, looking at the portraits of Agent H and High T fighting the Hive.

So how did C realize T was the traitor?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe C realised that as soon as High T covered H, he saved the world in almost an instant. As in like T is predicting the future. So maybe he went to T’s office and realised they were the only 2 there and that is maybe how he knew T was the traitor